# How to fill in missing dates using python for all ids

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe A with ID, date_yyyymmdd, amount and hours as shown below. Not all calendar dates are populated.

| id | date_yyyymmdd | amount | hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20230101 | 1428.95 | 11 |
| 1 | 20230103 | 1791.29 | 13 |
| 2 | 20230101 | 2516.84 | 15 |
| 2 | 20230105 | 3046.08 | 5 |
| 3 | 20230102 | 7137.92 | 11 |
| 3 | 20230103 | 1104.35 | 1 |
| 3 | 20230104 | 25 | 1 |

I would like to fill in missing calendar dates between two variables start_date and end_date and produce another dataframe B as shown below and populate amount and hours as 0s for those dates. In the example below the start date is 20230101 and end date is 20230105. I found a code that uses date as index and fills in missing value. I don't think it will work in my case. I want to fill dates for each id. How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

| id | date_yyyymmdd | amount | hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20230101 | 1428.95 | 11 |
| 1 | 20230102 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 20230103 | 1791.29 | 13 |
| 1 | 20230104 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 20230105 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 20230101 | 2516.84 | 15 |
| 2 | 20230102 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 20230103 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 20230104 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 20230105 | 3046.08 | 5 |
| 3 | 20230101 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 20230102 | 7137.92 | 11 |
| 3 | 20230103 | 1104.35 | 1 |
| 3 | 20230104 | 25 | 1 |
| 3 | 20230105 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way by constructing a new `MultiIndex`, and using that to `reindex` your df.

```
cols = ['id','date_yyyymmdd']

start_date = '1/1/2023'
end_date = '1/5/2023'

df['date_yyyymmdd'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_yyyymmdd'],format = '%Y%m%d')

df = (df.set_index(cols)
      .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['id'].unique(),pd.date_range(start_date,end_date,freq='D')],names = cols))
      .fillna(0)
      .sort_index()
      .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
    id date_yyyymmdd   amount  hours
0    1    2023-01-01  1428.95   11.0
1    1    2023-01-02     0.00    0.0
2    1    2023-01-03  1791.29   13.0
3    1    2023-01-04     0.00    0.0
4    1    2023-01-05     0.00    0.0
5    2    2023-01-01  2516.84   15.0
6    2    2023-01-02     0.00    0.0
7    2    2023-01-03     0.00    0.0
8    2    2023-01-04     0.00    0.0
9    2    2023-01-05  3046.08    5.0
10   3    2023-01-01     0.00    0.0
11   3    2023-01-02  7137.92   11.0
12   3    2023-01-03  1104.35    1.0
13   3    2023-01-04    25.00    1.0
14   3    2023-01-05     0.00    0.0
```

If you wanted to have the start and stop be different for each group, the following should work:

```
idx = (pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    df.groupby('id')['date_yyyymmdd'].agg(lambda x: pd.date_range(x.min(),x.max()))
    .explode()
    .reset_index()
    ))

(df.set_index(['id','date_yyyymmdd']).reindex(idx)
.fillna(0)
.reset_index()
.assign(date_yyyymmdd = lambda x: x['date_yyyymmdd'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df["date_yyyymmdd"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date_yyyymmdd"], format="%Y%m%d")
r = pd.date_range(df["date_yyyymmdd"].min(), df["date_yyyymmdd"].max())

df = (
    df.groupby("id", group_keys=False)
    .apply(
        lambda x: (newdf := x.set_index("date_yyyymmdd").reindex(r)).assign(
            id=newdf["id"].ffill().bfill()
        )
    )
    .reset_index()
    .fillna(0)
)
df["id"] = df["id"].astype(int)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        index  id   amount  hours
0  2023-01-01   1  1428.95   11.0
1  2023-01-02   1     0.00    0.0
2  2023-01-03   1  1791.29   13.0
3  2023-01-04   1     0.00    0.0
4  2023-01-05   1     0.00    0.0
5  2023-01-01   2  2516.84   15.0
6  2023-01-02   2     0.00    0.0
7  2023-01-03   2     0.00    0.0
8  2023-01-04   2     0.00    0.0
9  2023-01-05   2  3046.08    5.0
10 2023-01-01   3     0.00    0.0
11 2023-01-02   3  7137.92   11.0
12 2023-01-03   3  1104.35    1.0
13 2023-01-04   3    25.00    1.0
14 2023-01-05   3     0.00    0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [pyjanitor's](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) function:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df['date_yyyymmdd'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_yyyymmdd'],format = 'ISO8601')
# create variable containing all possible dates
dates = {"date_yyyymmdd": pd.date_range("2023-01-01", "2023-01-05", freq="D")}
df.complete('id', dates, fill_value=0)
    id date_yyyymmdd   amount  hours
0    1    2023-01-01  1428.95     11
1    1    2023-01-02     0.00      0
2    1    2023-01-03  1791.29     13
3    1    2023-01-04     0.00      0
4    1    2023-01-05     0.00      0
5    2    2023-01-01  2516.84     15
6    2    2023-01-02     0.00      0
7    2    2023-01-03     0.00      0
8    2    2023-01-04     0.00      0
9    2    2023-01-05  3046.08      5
10   3    2023-01-01     0.00      0
11   3    2023-01-02  7137.92     11
12   3    2023-01-03  1104.35      1
13   3    2023-01-04    25.00      1
14   3    2023-01-05     0.00      0
```